# Diff not working as I expect

Tags: shell-script, diff

I have 2 file, `a.txt` and `b.txt` and I want to compare them.

`a.txt` contains:

```
abc
jkl < jkl
mno > mno
pqr <> pqr
```

`b.txt` contains:

```
abc
jkl < jkl
mno > mno
pqr <> pqrs
stu
```

I'm using this script:

```
$ diff a.txt b.txt | grep "> " | cut -c3- > c.txt
```

Which results in `c.txt`:

```
pqr <> pqr
pqr <> pqrs
stu
```

Why is `pqr <> pqr` being included in the results? How can I resolve this?

Comment: `grep '^> '`. That is, look for `> ` only at the start of the line. What has ssh to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

As @StephaneChazelas stated in the comments, this would appear to have nothing to do with SSH. Running everything locally I get the same results as you, mainly:

```
$ diff a.txt b.txt | grep "> " | cut -c3-
pqr <> pqr
pqr <> pqrs
stu
```

The `diff` command is identifying lines that are different and the line `pqr <> pqrs` is unique among the 2 files. You can use a side by side diff to see which lines are lining up if it helps.

```
$ diff -y a.txt b.txt
abc                                                             abc
jkl < jkl                                                       jkl < jkl
mno > mno                                                       mno > mno
pqr <> pqr                                                    | pqr <> pqrs
                                                              > stu
```

Lines that are similar but not identical are marked with a <kbd>|</kbd>. Lines that are unique are marked with a <kbd>></kbd> if only in file #2, or a <kbd><</kbd> if only present in file #1. Identical lines do not show any such marking.

Answer (score 1):

As @StephaneChazelas noted, you forgot to anchor your regular expression, so the `"> "` will match the `>` in the line `pqr <> pqr` that is only in `a.txt`.

But it looks like you want a filter to only show the lines that are new or changed in `b.txt`. If you are using GNU diff, it offers you some options to achieve this directly:

```
$ diff --old-line-format '' --unchanged-line-format '' --new-line-format '%L' a.txt b.txt 
pqr <> pqrs
stu
```

The `--old-line-format ''` removes all lines that are not in `b.txt`, the `--unchanged-line-format ''` removes all lines common to both files and the `--new-line-format '%L'` shows just the line contents for all new or changed lines in `b.txt`. The leading `>` is suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have extra white spaces.

try

```
diff -w -B file1.txt file2.txt
```

-w Ignore all white space.

-B Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.